# When python does import, does it import names in 'import' statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't have a very clear understanding of python's import mechanism. One thing that confuses me is: when python imports a module, does it also imports the names imported there. Here is the code:

```
# A.py
def A_func():
   pass;

# B.py
from A import *;
def B_func():
   pass;

# C.py
from B import *;
def C_func():
   # I can use B_func, OK, no problem.
   # I can use A_func here, is import recursive?
```

If python recursively imports, is my code a bad pratice? What happens if I add

```
from A import *;
```

to C.py? Does it cause any overhead by importing twice? Or should I avoid 'from xx import *' and only import the needed name?

Thanks!

Comment: `import *` is (always) a bad practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is only executed the first time `import` is called for a module. Subsequent imports only copy names and references.

Having said that, *don't import `*`*.

Comment: Meaning if a name X is imported in a module A, if I import everything in A, I get access to that name X, right?

Comment: Depends on what's in `A.__all__`.

Answer (score -1):

you can only use B_func in C.py. You won't be able to access A_Func. You have to import from A if you want to use definitions in A.
Edit: Sorry, My bad. I was under wrong understanding

Comment: I have thought the same, but... I can use A_func in C, as A_func is imported by B in *. This doesn't accord with my understanding of import, hence this question.

Comment: @manish That's just not true. If `B.py` imports stuff from `A.py` into its namespace, it is in the namespace and can be imported from elsewhere. Although that isn't very good style in the most cases. If `C.py` needs something from `A.py`, it should import it directly from there.